# Vmlinuz Question

Tags: kernel, windows, icons

So, I am messing with nemo (file manager) as root and I noticed something. `vmlinuz` has a Windows icon:

[image: vmlinuz with Windows icon]

I also noticed that when running as normal user, the icon is not present.

This is really strange. I think it is happening on Nautilus (another file manager) too. Can someone explain this?

Comment: It looks like you're running a custom theme, or custom icon theme. Do these icons change if you switch back to the standard Ubuntu theme?

Answer (score 0):

`vmlinuz` is part of the kernel along with `initrd.img`.

Together you could say they form the 'Operating System' like Windows is.  It could be a coding error by 'nemo' folks. Don't delete it.

The real files are kept in `/boot` and `vmlinuz` along with `vmlinuz.old` are symbolic links to the real files:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ ll /boot/vmlinuz*
-rw------- 1 root root 5836336 Nov 11 07:15 /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5017584 Oct 18 13:28 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-113-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7060896 Nov 19 11:34 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6988624 Nov 19 21:01 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.33-040433-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7046080 Jun 24 12:46 /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.3-040603-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3974752 Aug 16 02:44 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.1-040701-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4134688 Aug 20 11:42 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.2-040702-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4134688 Sep  7 01:45 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-040703-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4138784 Sep 24 03:50 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.5-040705-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 4994848 Oct  7 08:50 /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.1-040801-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7427872 Oct 22 05:46 /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.4-040804-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7427872 Nov 19 11:24 /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.5-040805-generic
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ ll /vmlinuz*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Nov 19 20:49 /vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.33-040433-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov  9 17:00 /vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$
```

When Nautilus is called by root user the `/` directory looks looks like this:

[image: Nautilus Root User]

As you can see there is no Windows icon like `nemo` uses but there is a unique looking icon used by `nautilus`.

These symbolic links in the `/` directory are simply handy references to show you which kernel you've currently booted with, and which kernel you booted with before that.

Comment: This doesn't definitively answer the actual question of why the Windows icon appears for root or why it doesn't appear at all for normal users. Your wording strongly suggests that you're guessing. You also mention `initrd.img.old` instead of the more likely (non-"old") `initrd.img`. While the filenames can be used to more easily recover your system by using much shorter, easier-to-remember filenames for the kernel executable (`/vmlinuz`) and initial ram disk image (`/initrd.img`), they're also there so that programs can easily access the currently selected default kernel and ram disk image.

Comment: Was working from phone and didn't notice second initrd.img. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex improved the answer using my computer. I encourage you to post an answer as well using your superior experience over my limited knowledge.